# toggle class Javascript not showing

Tags: javascript

I have created with javascript several Li elemnts in a ul, now I have a button to change the clase on them also created with JS, I am using the toogle function and when I console log the elemnt i can see that it adds and removes the class name but the element is not changing the decoration, I verified that the css file is properly linked by editing other elements, did anyone had the same issue or knows how to solve it?.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="cssfunctions.css">
</head>
<body>

  <input type="text" id="size">
  <button id="submit">Sumbit</button>
  <ul id="output">

  </ul>


    <script src="ja.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```css
.none{
    text-decoration: line-through;
    color:green;
    background-color: aqua;
}
```

the js to change the class

```js
function checkItem(e){
  let item = e.target.parentNode;
item.classList.toggle(".none");
console.log(e.target.parentNode)
}
```

hope you can clarify since I really tried many different things and none works, the console log gives this

```html
<li class=".none">//first click

<li class="">//second click
```

Comment: Change to `item.classList.toggle("done");`. The dot is not given here.

Comment: thanks, it works!!, i knew it should be sth sily, i will keep it in mind in the future, whenever you declare the id or class in the query there is no need to add the "." or "#".

Comment: In the query it is necessary! But not in the classList.toggle() method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you want to toggle class `none`. The classList.toggle() method receives the className directly, not a selector. So change from `.none` to `none`.

```js
function checkItem(e){
  let item = e.target.parentNode;
  item.classList.toggle("none");
  console.log(e.target.parentNode)
}
```